# Calling nested RepeaterItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-2.0

I constructed a Repeater for my XML file roughly like so:

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="samplexml.xml" XPath="level1/level2" />
<asp:Repeater id="category" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">

<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="category">
    <h2><%#XPath("@name") %></h2>

    <asp:Repeater id="group" runat="server" DataSource='<%# XPathSelect("group") %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
        ...
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

    </div>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

And now I'm working on how to get the data inside of each on postback. I learned roughly how to get into a RepeaterItem:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem items in category.Items)
{   
    Output.Text += items.UniqueID + "<br />";
}
```

But after a lot of searching MSDN, this site, and others, I haven't been able to figure out how to get into the `group` repeater.

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything obvious.  In my experience working with nested Repeaters/ListViews/Etc is a nightmare.

If you have the option to do this using MVC I would recommend that.  If not.... Your best bet is probably to get familiar with FindControl.  Typically your code will look something like this:

```
protected void category_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater level2 = e.Item.FindControl("group") as Repeater;
    //you are now working with the nested repeater in a single row...  Do what you will!
}
```

So when a row in the parent repeater binds, you will have to use FindControl to find it's nested repeater.  Good luck!

Comment: I put this in, and it didn't throw any errors. However, nothing happens. Do I need to call categories_ItemDataBound() somewhere to activate this?

Comment: You probably need to specify this function in the ItemBound event when you define the repeater on your ASPX page.

Comment: Ahh! Got something out of that! Thanks for your help and patience...I don't like asking about things that are probably really basic.

Comment: No worries.  As I mentioned nested repeaters are a pain.  Do follow up on displaying nested data using MVC (even if it's not for this particular project), I think you will be pleasantly surprised!